# Django+postgres auth_user duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"

Tags: django, postgresql

```
    try:
        django_user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        django_user = User(username=self.username)
    django_user.is_staff=True
    django_user.save()
```

Above gets the user by searching by username if present or create a new object if not present and updates its attribute and saves it back to db.

This code ideally should handle the situation where the object is already present in the database. But it is throwing following error

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=(xxxxxxxx@yyyyy.com) already 
         exists.
```

I don't get the reason for this. Searched on the internet and found that It might be because of indices are corrupted and has to reset the sequence but Cannot find the exact reason and solution for this.
Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should use `create_user` to make user.

Comment: Are you sure the first transaction - creating the user - is finishing before you then query to see if the user exists?  I doubt it's the indices, I've had this sort of thing happen many times and it is pretty much always either a race condition, that you're not properly saving the new object, or that you're somehow not querying the user table correctly.

Comment: can post the  console log ,and more code

Comment: @Dave . I also checked out and found that I might be related to indices. can tell how to reset the indices for this. or how can I solve it.

Comment: @RohitNegi the simplest way to check that would be to just start with an empty database and see if it works or not. If it still doesn't work, it's not the index.

Comment: It is an intermittent problem. Does not always happen.

Answer (score 0):

I've been a while since i don't refresh my Django skills but as far i remember you 
can use another way to surpass this problem like:

```
if Entry.objects.filter(username=self.username).exists():
    # DO IF STUFF
else:
    # DO ELSE STUFF
```

If your username isn't the pk key then you may have to set it as **unique** and that would prevent to have duplicated usernames.

[Oficial Django reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/querysets/)

But there is something it is digging in my mind by the way you are using your self.username variable. It seems you have some class where you needs to make such kind of functionality. And i'm afraid that this peace of code you have is located inside of the same class model declaration, by the kind of query you wants to perform you should keep this in mind:

If you wants to check for some username that hasn't been insert in the databse yet then it won't have a pk and you won't be able to look for such data in the database. By summoning it before the .save() some of this errors can happen.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: if the code snippet you suggested. Is it targeted to solve this problem. If so, what is that cause which does not occur in code snippet you shared

Comment: If I am getting it right. I am pretty sure I am not saving the object between first and last statement of code I have shared. after ```try:
        django_user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        django_user = User(username=self.username)``` and before ```django_user.save()```. there is not other save.

Comment: Can you add in your problem description the user model you are using?, is it the default User Model from django . Please extend a bit the code snipet of your function.